# Are Sasakian metrics (associated to bumpy metrics) bumpy?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

**Some background** :

**(1)** Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold. Let $LM$ be the free loop space, the space of loops in $M$ of Sobolev class $W^{1,2}$. There is the energy functional $E:LM\to \mathbb{R}$ associated to the free loop space, given by

$E:\gamma\to \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{S^1}g(\gamma'(\theta),\gamma'(\theta))d\theta.$

The critical points of $E$ are closed geodesics. A metric $g$ is called $bumpy$ (or generic) if the circle worth of critical elements in $LM$ obtained by rotating a geodesic is a non-degenerate critical submanifold of $LM$.

**(2)** For any Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ there is a natural metric $g_S$ on the tangent bundle $TM$ called the $Sasaki\,\, metric$, defined using the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ for $g$. This restricts to a metric on $T_1 M$, the unit tangent bundle of $M$.

---

**Question 1**  *Let $g$ be a bumpy metric on $M$. Is the associated Sasakian metric $g_S$ on $TM$ (or on $T_1 M$) bumpy?*

**Question 2**  *Are there other natural metrics on $TM$ (like Cheeger-Gromov metrics) which are bumpy when they arise from bumpy metrics?*